# Mplcursor hover showing _line0 on data points

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, mplcursors

Does anybody know why I would be getting "_line0" on certain points when using mplcursor hover on rectangles? I created a bunch of rectangles in a subplot and used the following code to create a cursor to show annotation when hovering over them:

```
def update_annotation(sel):
    """ update the annotation belonging to the current selected item (sel) """
    # get the label of the graphical element that is selected
    label = sel.artist.get_label()
    #point = sel.artist[sel.target.index]
    # change the text of the annotation
    sel.annotation.set_text(label)
    sel.annotation.set(position=(1, 10), anncoords="offset points")
    sel.annotation.get_bbox_patch().set(fc="yellow", alpha = 1)
    sel.annotation.arrow_patch.set(arrowstyle="simple", fc="yellow", alpha=.5)

# create an mplcursor object that shows an annotation while hovering
cursor = mplcursors.cursor(axs[1], hover=True)
# call the function "update_annotation" each time a new element gets hovered over
cursor.connect("add", update_annotation)
```

However, when I hover over certain datapoint, not only is it REALLY slow to go to where I'm hovering over but it also shows me this:

[image]

My guess is that there are too many overlapping data points? If so, does anybody know a way around that and also can somebody explain to me what _line0 even means?

I realize the cursor is hovering over an empty space in the plot but it also shows _line0 when I hover over rectangles. Sometimes it will even show the label and then go back to _line0.

Comment: These questions are really really hard to answer without example code and data that reproduces the problem. `mplcursors.cursor(axs[1], hover=True)` attaches the cursor to all graphical elements belonging to `axs[1]`. One of these seems to be a line or curve with internal label `_line0` (all elements automatically get a default label starting with "_").  Depending on how the desired elements are created, you could try `mplcursors.cursor(axs[1].patches, hover=True)`, limiting the annotations to patches.  Or maybe `axs[1].collections` if the annotations are needed for `collections`.

Comment: An alternative is to make a list while creating the elements and providing this list as first parameter to `mplcursors.cursor`.  (Probably not needed, but in `update_annotation` you could set `sel.annotation.set_visible(False)` when the label starts with a "_".)

Comment: That worked! Thank you. I created the rectangles using patches so putting axs[1].patches limited it to just extract the patches. Had no idea about the internal label automatically created. Thanks so much!